# Plotting the below json in a HighChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

Following is a json object in Json format 1.1

```
    {
       "JSONVersion":1.1,
       "DataBehaviour":"Timebased",
       "MeasurementUnit":"MB",
       "Error":"",
       "DataSeries":[
          {
             "name":"AvailableMBytes",
             "data":[
                {
                   "x":1396602300000,
                   "y":"1156"
                },
                {
                   "x":1396605900000,
                   "y":"1137.05"
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
}
```

Is it possible to plot the data in high chart? My code look like this, but doesn't show any output.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data1) {
        options.series[0].data = data1.data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
         });

});
```

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to set something like this: `options.series = data1.DataSeries;` ?  Also, do your `y` values need to be strings (`"y":"1137.05"`)? Can not be simple value: `"y": 1137.05` ?

Comment: if multiple items in DataSeries array (as it suppose to be) simply it could be done by the way suggested by @PawełFus ,that means
       
       $.getJSON('data.json', function(data1) { 
            $.each(data1.DataSeries,function(item){
                         options.series = item;
                         var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                         })
          
            });

Comment: and better to have addSeries(item) function to add a series for each item in DataSeries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if its an array as shown in question , iterate over it
here is link for [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/BxbUmIkq6WaYw4FDbOBS?p=preview)

The json need to have number instead strings:

```
{
   "JSONVersion":1.1,
   "DataBehaviour":"Timebased",
   "MeasurementUnit":"MB",
   "Error":"",
   "DataSeries":[
      {
         "name":"AvailableMBytes",
         "data":[
            {
               "x":1396602300000,
               "y":1156 
            },
            {
               "x":1396605900000,
               "y":1137.05
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

and the charting code

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data1) { 
    options.series[0].data = data1.DataSeries[0].data;
    options.series[0].name = data1.DataSeries[0].name;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
     });
```

You can directly put "item" in series as it has name as well as data in it.

Comment: I am getting an error `TypeError: obj is undefined
.each()
 jquery-1.11.3.js:358
<anonymous>
 new%201.html:19
jQuery.Callbacks/fire()
 jquery-1.11.3.js:3148
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith()
 jquery-1.11.3.js:3260
done()
 jquery-1.11.3.js:9314
.send/callback()`

Comment: Please see http://plnkr.co/edit/BxbUmIkq6WaYw4FDbOBS?p=preview , your json has strings instead of numbers. also you want to plot multiple spline or single ?